# Search functionality using Google API throwing "operation aborted"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Sometime back we implemented `search` using google however it has stopped working now. Please find code below

```
var siteDetails = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=';

function LoadRecordsFromGoogle(jobTitle, country, searchArea, pageNo) {

    var searchText = jobTitle;

    if (searchArea != undefined && searchArea != '') {
        searchText += " jobs in " + searchArea;
    } else if (country != undefined && country != '') {
        searchText += " jobs in " + country;
    }

    ajaxUrl = siteDetails + pageNo + '&rsz=large&q=' + searchText + '&callback=myjsonpfunction1';

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: myjsonpfunction1,
        async: 'true',
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(error) {
            debugger;
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

However now we are getting error

> Operation aborted with Status 0